# ie8 update value event

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, backbone.js

I have been staring at this for 2 hours. The purpose is for when a user tabs out of a field, the value will be converted in to two digits.

For some reason IE8 Chokes on this the first time you try it but it works the second time. After that it occasionally breaks.

// backbone snippit

```
events: {
  'blur [name=month], [name=day], [name=year]': 'sanitizeAge'
},

'sanitizeAge': function(e) {
  var view = this;
  var $el = $(e.target);
  var $val = $el.val();

  if($val.length === 1){
    $el.val('0'+$val);  
  }
},
```

// html snippet

```
   <div class="padded grid-quarter">
        <input name="month" type="text" placeholder="MM" class="grid-whole text-field month" data-validate="month" data-min="2" maxlength="2" tabindex="3">
    </div>
    <div class="padded grid-quarter">
        <input name="day" type="text" placeholder="DD" class="grid-whole text-field day" data-validate="day" data-min="2" maxlength="2" tabindex="4">
    </div>
    <div class="padded grid-half">
       <input name="year" type="text" placeholder="Year of Birth" class="text-field grid-whole  year" data-validate="year" data-min="4" maxlength="4" tabindex="5">
    </div>

</fieldset>
```

Comment: Starting with the obvious... could you try using onchange instead of the blur event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simplified version of your answer:

```
'sanitizeAge': function(e) {
  var val = e.target.value;
  if (val.length === 1){
    e.target.value = '0'+val;
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work only by getting the value via javascript instead of jquery.

```
'sanitizeAge': function(e) {
  var view = this;
  var $el = $(e.target);
  var $val = $el[0].value; // <---- FIX

  if($val.length === 1){
    $el.val('0'+$val);  
  }
},
```